# Unable to pause when trying to save EditText

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, state

Hi people of Stack......
I am trying to get my app to save the text with the `EditText` box so that when the user closes the app and re-opens it there entry fields stay saved, but I am getting an `NPE` when clicking my button.

Please assist me :)

```
package com.smarte.smartipcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IPEntry extends Activity {
    public final static String ACTUALSMARTIP = "com.smarte.smartipcontrol.ACTU_IP";
    private EditText editText;
    private EditText editText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_ipentry);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.act_ipentry, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the SendIP button */
    public void sendip(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IPControl.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
        String actu_ip = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(ACTUALSMARTIP, actu_ip);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
        if (restoredText != null) {
            editText.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
            int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
            if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }
            SharedPreferences prefs2 = getPreferences(1); 
            String restoredText2 = prefs2.getString("text2", null);
            if (restoredText2 != null) {
                editText2.setText(restoredText2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                int selectionStart2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-start2", -1);
                int selectionEnd2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-end2", -1);
                if (selectionStart2 != -1 && selectionEnd2 != -1) {
                    editText2.setSelection(selectionStart2, selectionEnd2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putString("text", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("selection-start", editText.getSelectionStart());
        editor.putInt("selection-end", editText.getSelectionEnd());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getPreferences(1).edit();
        editor2.putString("text2", editText2.getText().toString());
        editor2.putInt("selection-start2", editText2.getSelectionStart());
        editor2.putInt("selection-end2", editText2.getSelectionEnd());
        editor2.commit();
    }   
}
```

LogCat

```
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.smarte.smartipcontrol/com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPEntry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3016)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPEntry.onPause(IPEntry.java:72)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3002)
12-17 13:20:20.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: All of the issues with your code seem to stem from a lack of understanding of Java. I would strongly suggest you take a bit of time to brush up on your Java skills before delving too deeply into Android development. It will make your life much easier =)

Comment: Which line is line 72? I suspect `editor.putString("text", editText.getText().toString());`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't ever see you instantiating `editText2`, which you will probably get acknowlegded once you check line 72: `at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPEntry.onPause(IPEntry.java:72)` (can be `editText` as well, see my edit).

Since `editText` and `editText2` (poor name choices, by the way) are global variables, you should instantiate them in the `onCreate()`:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.theSecondEditText);
```

**Edit**: by the way, in `sendIp` you are instantiating a **local** variable `editText`, which means not only `editText2` is `null`, `editText` also is `null`! You should ***never*** have both global and local variables with the same name (except for constructors, and then using the `this` keyword).

Comment: Good catch on the last point. I didn't notice the dupe `editText`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is that you are never instantiating `editText2` so it is null when you try call `getText()` on it to retrieve the value to store.

On an unrelated note: `editText` and `editText2` are really really poor choices for variable names. You should always strive to make your variable names descriptive enough that you can tell what they are without having to hunt around. Perhaps you should consider something like `ipEntryTxt` for one of them?

**EDIT:** also note you should probably move this line:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
```

to be inside of onCreate() instead of inside `sendip()` As your code is now if the user opened this activity but never presses the button (to call sendip()) then `editText` will be null by the time onPause() fires which will give you a null pointer exception also.